# Compare two dict and change keys in second if keys exists as sub-value in first

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, matching

Need help remapping the keys for `d2` if they match the value for `id` in `d1`. In case there are keys that are unmatched, drop them.

```py
d1={'A':{'id':'a'},'B':{'id':'b'}}
d2={'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}
```

Expected output:

```py
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
```

Comment: Your title says you're changing keys in the first dictionary, but your post says you're remapping the keys for d2. Can you give another example to clarify how this should work?

Comment: @kcsquared thanks for the heads up my mistake - made edits

Comment: Just to clarify, should `d1={'A':{'id':'a'},'B':{'id':'b'}} d2={'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}` map d2 to `{'A':1,'B':2, 'c':3}` ? Your example doesn't help distinguish what you want.

Comment: I see - in that case `c` should drop. I made more changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could traverse `d1` and use `d2` as a lookup to modify values:

```
for k, d in d1.items():
    d1[k] = d2.get(d['id'])
```

If you want to modify `df2` instead, you could use a dict comprehension:

```
d2 = {k: d2.get(d['id']) for k, d in d1.items()}
```

or use two loops (once to modify values of keys that exist in `df1` and once to remove any keys that don't exist in `df1`):

```
for k, d in d1.items():
    d2[k] = d2.pop(d['id'])
for k in list(d2.keys() - d1.keys()):
    d2.pop(k)
```

Output:

```
{'A': 123, 'B': 123}
```

Comment: my bad I meant remap second `d2` not first `d1`

Comment: `{k: d2.get(d['id']) for k, d in d1.items()}` works for me cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're after

```py
d1={'A':{'id':'a'},'B':{'id':'b'}}
d2={'a':123,'b':123}

for key, id_map in d1.copy().items():  # view over soft copy won't mutate
    try:
        d1[key] = d2[id_map["id"]]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

```py
>>> d1
{'A': 123, 'B': 123}
```

However, unmapped values will remain the same (ie if there is `C`, but no `id` in its mapping, or no `c` in `d2`..)

```py
>>> d1={'A':{'id':'a'},'B':{'id':'b'},'C':{'id':'c'}}
[..]
>>> d1
{'A': 123, 'B': 123, 'C': {'id': 'c'}}
```

If you want to discard unmapped values, you could do so here with `del d1[key]` in the except or simply create a new dict to pack the keys and values into (never added if KeyError is raised)
Alternatively, if this is an error (ie. `C` *must* exist), you can simply let `KeyError` raise to the caller and have it deal with the consequences

Comment: thanks for this however I made a mistake I needed to remap the second dictionary not the first

Comment: hmm.. can you update your Question with the expected output? (also it often doesn't matter if you modify or re-create a dict)

Answer (score 0):

As long as each 'val' appears at most once in `d1`'s subdictionaries (i.e. the key: {'id': val} pairs in `d1`), you can iterate over `d1`'s items like so:

```py
d1 = {'A': {'id': 'a'}, 'B': {'id': 'b'}, 'C': {'id': 'c'}}
d2 = {'a': 123, 'b': 12, 'd': 8}

d3 = {k: d2[v['id']] for k, v in d1.items() if v['id'] in d2}
print(d3)
```

```py
>>> {'A': 123, 'B': 12}
```

Since you need to check all key-value pairs in `d1`, this is the best you can do in terms of time and space efficiency.

However, if you will be 're-keying' many `d2` dictionaries with the same `d1`, it may be faster to build  a reverse-index to reuse:

```py
reverse_mapping = {v['id']: k for k, v in d1.items()}
def rekey(dict_to_rekey, reverse_map):
    return {reverse_map[k]: dict_to_rekey[k] 
            for k in dict_to_rekey.keys() & reverse_map.keys()}

d3 = rekey(d2, reverse_mapping)
```